# XMLHTTPREQUEST error JQUERY

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest, getjson, codepen

I am working with dark sky API on code pen. https://codepen.io/ashan_zeroxster/pen/MpxVOv?editors=0010
And when I tried to get JSON data from DARKSKY API I get XMLHTTPREQUEST error.
My Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var api = https://api.darksky.net/forecast/a18d80cbf99f8930c6a140bf8e722630/";
 var long = "";
 var lat = ""; 
 var url = "";

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position){
var long = position.coords.longitude;
var lat =  position.coords.latitude;

var url =  api + long + "," + lat;

$.getJSON(url, function(data){
   document.write(data);
});



});                                      

 });
```

Comment: which error do you get? ..

Answer (score 0):

The problem in codepen seems to be CORS (Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing) violation. Read more on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

You also find information directly from darksky about CORS in their FAQ: https://darksky.net/dev/docs/faq

Comment: How do i call the API behind the scenes? So that the API key is not exposed. Can I use AJAX call instead of getJSON method here to solve this issue

Comment: Thanks for your Help! I was able to solve this issue using the JSONP technique. https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/